# Intermittent 503 issue with JVM proxy parameters on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, proxy, resttemplate

I am facing an intermittent issue on tomcat while making a rest call. 
Setup:

**ApplicationA** running on standalone tomcat on **portX**

**ApplicationB** running on another standalone tomcat on **portY**
both the tomcat installations are on the same machine. 
Java version is JRE6

Following parameters are added to the JVM_OPTS in bash profile
-Dhttp.proxyHost=[host] -Dhttp.proxyPort=[port] -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*localhost*

Application A makes a rest call to application B using Spring RestTemplate and gets a 503 error (Service unavailable) response.

The URL being used is http://localhost:portY/ApplicationB/restapipath

I cause is that the requests to localhost are going through the proxy defined in JVM_OPTS, but as per my understanding all localhost urls should be called without using any proxy.

**This issue is happening intermittently, but once it starts it continues till I restart the ApplicationA tomcat server.**

Also, my understanding is that any calls made through Spring RestTemplate will honour the JAVA_OPTS proxy settings without any additional handling in the code.

Any pointers, help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the comunication between the two applications work, when you start then without the JVM_OPT ?

Comment: That is one thing that i cannot try since it is a production system and ApplicationA needs proxy to communicate with other systems. I know it's lame to not have a reliable test system.

Comment: Could it be that the 2nd webservice call to an external system be causing the intermittent issue with proxies ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of frustration I found the solution.
The problem was that **my understanding about JVM proxy parameters was incorrect**.

Parameters in `JVM_OPTS` in bash profile `-Dhttp.proxyHost=[host] -Dhttp.proxyPort=[port]` are actually not used automatically when using Spring `RestTemplate`. These parameters have to be fetched using `System.getProperty('http.proxyHost')` and then explicitly set in the `DefaultHttpClient`

Now the issue in my code was that there was a single `httpClient` bean defined in the `applicationContext.xml` which was being used by both the rest calls. The non-proxy rest call worked fine until the with-proxy rest call updated `httpClient` object with the proxy details.

Solution was to user separate `httpClient` objects for both rest calls.